# rails redirect base on ip address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

with the app am building, am trying to redirect users base on ipadress,

```
def check_country
  # binding.pry
  if !gambian_blocks.any? { |block| block.include?(request.remote_ip) }
    redirect_to subscribe_path
  end
end
def gambian_blocks
    %w{
      197.242.143.0/24
      197.255.207.0/24
      212.60.95.0/24
    }.map { |subnet| IPAddr.new subnet }
  end
```

with this am trying to redirect any ip address thats not from Gambia to the subscribe page, currently this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
def check_country
  request_ip = IPAddr.new request.remote_ip # => Parse from text to IP Address
  unless gambian_blocks.any? { |block| block.include?(request_ip) }
    redirect_to subscribe_path
  end
end
```

EDIT

You could also use the [geoip](https://github.com/cjheath/geoip) gem. It supports IPV4 & IPV6. You could do something like this:

```
ip = GeoIP.new('GeoLiteCityv6.dat').city(request.remote_ip)
ip.contry_name # => 'Gambia'
```

Comment: That's because the request.remote_ip is ipv6. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`request.remote_ip` returns a string value whereas `gambian_blocks` returns an array of `IPAddr` objects. So they cannot be compared. So convert to a similar format to desired result.

Comment: whats the best way to do it?

Comment: Try replacing `request.remote_ip` with `IPAddr.new(request.remote_ip)`

Comment: Did you mean this by the if condition? `if gambian_blocks.any? and !gambian_blocks.include?IPAddr.new(request.remote_ip) }`

Comment: `if gambian_blocks.any? and !gambian_blocks.include?IPAddr.new(request.remote_ip)
    redirect_to subscribe_path
  end` my ip adress is gambia and getting redirected to subscribe which should not happen

Comment: try debugging the code to find the exact scenario whether you have your ip listed in the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138247/discussion-between-sajin-and-geniuskid-kanyi).